# How much does Qatar Airways charge for extra baggage?

Tags: qatar-airways

How much does Qatar Airways charge for extra baggage per kilo from Cairo Egypt to Entebbe Uganda?

Comment: Maybe try checking [Qatar Airways](https://www.qatarairways.com/en-qa/baggage/excess.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your class of service and at what time your are buying (preferred vs standard rate). For flights between Qatar and Africa they don't seem to charge by weight but there is a charge for an extra piece. Standard rate is USD$130. There is an extra charge of USD $75 if the bag is heavier than 23kg.